# Angular 4 - Conditional CSS Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm working on an Angular 4 app, where we present the user with a login. The login may fail, and on return, we listen for the error:-

```
.subscribe(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
```

This shows fine and we show this:-

```
<div *ngIf="error">
   <p class="error-message">{{ error.ExceptionMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

Above this is a standard input field for username and password with a class. I wanted to be able to add an `error` class to this without doing the following:-

```
<div *ngIf="error">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div *ngIf="!error">
    <input type="email" class="form-control error-field" />
</div>
```

Is there a better way than rendering the input twice, on each side of the if?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this using the class binding:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" [class.error-field]="error">
```

Answer (score 13):

yeah there's a better way using `ngClass` attribute like this:

```
<input type="email" [ngClass]="{'form-control': true, 'error-field': error}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for NgClass or NgStyle:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass
https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle